# How to seralize custom objects into stream (WCF HttpBinding - TransferMode = Streamed)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, c#-3.0, wcf-binding

I would like to know how to serialize custom objects into stream and send the stream via WCF Service. I am thinking to use XMLSerializer and serialize the objects into MemoryStream and pass it to Stream-type parameter of OperationContract method from client and when the request is received from the service, the Stream will be deserialized back to objects.

Your suggestion would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The Streamed mode it should be used when you want to transfer big data.
The Streamed mode may add some overhead on transport layer.
Also you lose automatically serialization provided by WCF.

*UPDATE*
XmlSerializer is not good for big data cause it use DOM. DOM parser loads entire xml content in memory and you will lose the benenfits of streaming (generating/consumming chunck by chunck of data).
Binary or Custom Serialization should be your way.
Also, don't forget to apply compression (more details http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dataservices/thread/12557249-2775-44e4-bc39-49585cf15873/)

Comment: Yes, I am planning to transfer large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here,

Serializing and streaming large custom objects:

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/06/10/streaming-large-content-with-wcf-and-deferred-execution.aspx